# Сохранение кириллицы из формы ввода php в бд mysql

Tags: php, html, utf-8, cp1251

Столкнулся с проблемой кодировки текста.Изначально была форма на главной странице сайта index.html с вводом текста в форму.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Some Title </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="addsometext.php"> Send <br>
    <br>
    <textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
    <br> <input type= submit value="ADD">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Файл addsometext.php

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect();


    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 die();
 }
 
 
 $a = explode("\r\n", $_POST['textarea']);

 
foreach ($a as $v) {
  //  echo " Текущее значение переменной \$a: $v.\r\n <br>";
 echo   $sql = "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES('" . $v . "')";
    $con->query($sql);
}
?>
```

В Mysql в сравнении utf8 . Все работало нормально добавлялся как русские буквы так и английские . И выводилось без проблем . Решил перенести форму ввода на другую страницу anotherpage.html и столкнулся с проблемой что текст сохраняется в бд в таком виде (&#1042 ;&#1080 ;&#1082 ;&#1090 ;&#1086 ;&#1088 ;). При использовании формы внутри php файла в бд сохраняет вот так(Р’РёРєС‚РѕСЂ).

```html
<?php

 // something there
 ?>


 
<form method = "post" action = "addsometext.php "> ADD names to bd <br> 
<br>
<textarea name="textarea"></textarea> 
<br>  <input type = submit value = "ADD"> 
</form>
```

P.S. В примерах неправильной кодировки имя "Виктор".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую указать в главном файле, или добавить в любой другой и сделать инклюд в главный файл(с инпутом) данный код:

```
mysql_query("SET names utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте явное указание кодировки на Вашей HTML странице, данные из формы будут закодированы соответственно:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
```

Также кодировку можно явным образом указать в самой форме:

```
<form method="post" action="addsometext.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
    ADD names to bd
    <br><br>
    <textarea name="textarea"></textarea> 
    <br>  
    <input type = submit value = "ADD"> 
</form>
```